# prototype chain of window.document

Tags: javascript, dom

When I enter in chrome console:

```
console.dir(window.document);
```

I get an object which has `HTMLDocument` as it prototype (`__proto__ : HTMLDocument`
)

This object has in turn `Document` as its prototype (`__proto__ : Document`
)

This object has in turn `Node` as its prototype (`__proto__ : Document`
)

---

In my current understanding `window.document` is the DOM and on this object are all sorts of functions which let us access the elements programmatically.

Are these other 3 links in the prototype chain also related to the DOM? Are they a part of the DOM?

Comment: Can find info on all of these in the MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument

Comment: As far as I know DOM is constructed of nodes (one of those nodes is the `document` object) and `DOM` is not an object itself that you can access, it is just the ensemble of those nodes. DOM is just a term we use to refer to that ensemble of nodes.

Comment: More about [**DOM on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM).